# Add Remove Class to a DOM element using only JavaScript, and best of these 2 ways

Tags: javascript

What is a good approach to add class to a DOM element using JavaScript. And Remove also.

I came across this following codes for **adding**:

1:

```
Element.prototype.addClassName = function (cls) {
    if (!this.hasClassName(cls)) {
        this.className = [this.className, cls].join(" ");
    }
};
```

2:

```
document.querySelector(element).classList.add(cls)
```

Both of them seem to work for me. What is the difference between them and which is the best?

Comment: jQuery does it really nicely, just properly attribute the work to jQuery and use theirs.

Comment: @TravisJ, I don't want to add an extra 90+ KB of JavaScript to my page, just for adding removing classes :)

Comment: Which browsers and versions do you want to support?

Comment: is hasClassName another function you already have access to?

Comment: I believe @TravisJ meant that you can look at how they do it and use their code :)

Comment: I think using the second one would be more suitable.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist

Comment: querySelector will be an issue if you need to support IE7

Comment: @kinakuta Query selector really isn't needed here. I don't know why the OP insists on it.

Comment: Btw `Element.prototype` stuff doesn't work in IE7.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, Thanks, did not know that for IE7

Comment: @TomPietrosanti, All old and new. IE6 as well. If there is really an awesome way that does not work with IE6, I am ready to give up IE6 only then

Comment: You should probably drop IE6 anyway, if possible.  Microsoft has stopped supporting it. http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**1**. If you are moved by the word **prototype**, you might want to check [MDN Docs - Inheritance and prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

**2**. The first code you mentioned is a normal cross-browser way of adding a class to an element.
Instead of being a function declaration, its added as a **method** to the **Element**'s prototype - so that when you query an Element by its `id` (good ol' JavaScript), you can simply call the method on the element itself.

**3**. The second code you have posted is per the **new DOM Specification**. [**W3 Link**](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-element-classlist).
It will work only in those browsers that implement the DOM Level 4 Specs. It won't work in old browsers.

That goes the difference.

For the best method, **a native method is always the best and fastest**.
So for the browsers that support `clasList`, the second should be the best. Per my opinion though, till things (drafts) are not finalized you might want to consider a method that works cross-browser and is compatible with both JavaScript (ECMA-3) and supported DOM Spec.

A simple idea should be to change the `className`, a property accessible in all new and old browsers, and append your `class` as a string to it:

```
var el = document.getElementById(id);
el.className = el.className + " " + cls; 
// mind the space while concatening
```

Of course you can add validation methods like using `regex` for trimming spaces while adding and removing.

By the way, I got the full part of the code you posted as the 1st Example:

```
Element.prototype.hasClassName = function(name) {
    return new RegExp("(?:^|\\s+)" + name + "(?:\\s+|$)").test(this.className);
};

Element.prototype.addClassName = function(name) {
    if (!this.hasClassName(name)) {
        this.className = this.className ? [this.className, name].join(' ') : name;
    }
};

Element.prototype.removeClassName = function(name) {
    if (this.hasClassName(name)) {
        var c = this.className;
        this.className = c.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|\\s+)" + name + "(?:\\s+|$)", "g"), "");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 8):

### This is jquery's code.

Adapted versions of **[jQuery's addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)** 
And **[jQuery's removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)**

If you look at jQuery source code, this is how they do it. This is adapted from them, but pretty much entirely written by jQuery and is their code. I am not the original author, and am merely showing how one piece can be used instead of the whole library.

jQuery's addClass:

```
//This code is jQuery's
function AddClassToElement(elem,value){
 var rspaces = /\s+/;
 var classNames = (value || "").split( rspaces );
 var className = " " + elem.className + " ",
 setClass = elem.className;
 for ( var c = 0, cl = classNames.length; c < cl; c++ ) {
  if ( className.indexOf( " " + classNames[c] + " " ) < 0 ) {
   setClass += " " + classNames[c];
  }
 }
 elem.className = setClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');//trim
}
```

jQuery's removeClass:

```
//This code is jQuery's
function RemoveClassFromElement(elem,value){
 var rspaces = /\s+/;
 var rclass = /[\n\t]/g
 var classNames = (value || "").split( rspaces );
 var className = (" " + elem.className + " ").replace(rclass, " ");
 for ( var c = 0, cl = classNames.length; c < cl; c++ ) {
  className = className.replace(" " + classNames[c] + " ", " ");
 }
 elem.className = className.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');//trim
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C5dvL/