# Best way to add class and remove it from all siblings using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery code is very simple:

```
$('.nav-menu').on('click','li', function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
```

upon click it adds class `selected` to selected `.nav-menu` element and removes that `selected` class from all siblings.

Best and shortest way to do **exact** the same with pure JavaScript?

Possible duplicate is 
[Not a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104881/add-remove-class-to-a-dom-element-using-only-javascript-and-best-of-these-2-way)

I need not just to add specific class. But also to remove that same class from all siblings of element.

Related HTML:

```
        <ul id="tabnav" class="nav-menu">
            <li class="tab selected"><a href="#">Element 1</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#">Element 2</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#">Element 3</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787383/how-to-add-remove-a-class-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add/remove a class in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787383/how-to-add-remove-a-class-in-javascript)

Comment: it is not duplicate, I have explained better. You also point me to very same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript? Then the **JS** code will look this for me:

```
function addClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList)
    el.classList.add(className)
  else if (!hasClass(el, className)) el.className += " " + className
}

function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList)
    el.classList.remove(className)
  else if (hasClass(el, className)) {
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)')
    el.className=el.className.replace(reg, ' ')
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Modern browsers have added classList:

```
document.getElementById('id').classList.add('YourClass'); //add
document.getElementById('id').classList.remove('YourClass'); //remove
```

Note: Not supported in IE <= 9 or Safari <=5.0